# How to call a function with no parameters to update interface?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to update my interface with the model I have.I have these two outlets in my `PFTableViewCell`:

```
class UserFeedCell: PFTableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var dislikeButton: UIButton!
```

I would like to update these two outlet buttons with the following code:

```
var vote: Int = 0 // initialize to user's existing vote, retrieved from the server
var likeCount: Int = 0 // initialize to existing like count, retrieved from the server
var dislikeCount: Int = 0 // initialize to existing dislike count, retrieved from the server

@IBAction func dislikeButton(sender: UIButton) {
    buttonWasClickedForVote(-1)
    print(likeCount)
    print(dislikeCount)
}

@IBAction func likeButton(sender: UIButton) {
    buttonWasClickedForVote(1)
    print(likeCount)
    print(dislikeCount) 
}

private func buttonWasClickedForVote(buttonVote: Int) {
    if buttonVote == vote {
        // User wants to undo her existing vote.
        applyChange(-1, toCountForVote: vote)
        vote = 0
    }

    else {
        // User wants to force vote to toggledVote.
        // Undo current vote, if any.
        applyChange(-1, toCountForVote: vote)

        // Apply new vote.
        vote = buttonVote
        applyChange(1, toCountForVote: vote)
    }
}

private func applyChange(change: Int, toCountForVote vote: Int ) {
    if vote == -1 { dislikeCount += change }
    else if vote == 1 { likeCount += change }
}

private func updateUserInterfaceFromModel() {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as! UserFeedCell
    cell.likeButton.selected = vote == 1
    cell.dislikeButton.selected = vote == -1
    cell.likeButton.setTitle("\(likeCount)", forState: .Normal)
    cell.dislikeButton.setTitle("\(dislikeCount)", forState: .Normal)
}
```

How can I update my outlets? I tried calling in `viewDidLoad` but my outlets aren't updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this :-

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "TableViewCell" // your cell identifier name in storyboard 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PFTableViewCell
    cell.likeButton.selected = vote == 1
    cell.dislikeButton.selected = vote == -1
    cell.likeButton.titleLabel!.text = "\(likeCount)"
    cell.dislikeButton.titleLabel!.text = "\(dislikeCount)"
    return cell
}
```

After the Question Updated, You can use awakeFromNib to achieve this task ...

```
class UserFeedCell: PFTableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var dislikeButton: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    likeButton.titleLabel!.text = "\(likeCount)"
    dislikeButton.titleLabel!.text = "\(dislikeCount)"
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: I updated my code.. i need to call the function not update the tableview cell. is there any way i can call the updateuserinterfacefrommodel into the cell?

Comment: thanks but the likeCount and dislikeCount are in a different class.. they are in the TableViewController. How can i access them?

Comment: You can insert those functions to the PFTableViewCell class

Comment: hey your code worked! but it is updating every cell for like/dislikeCount.. is there any way i can just update the one i'm clicking on??

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is not the right place for setting properties on `UITableViewCell`. You have to wait for iOS asking for a cell and then you can set the properties on cell and return it. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is the right method for this. You also need to ensure that properties are set correctly for right cell (using `indexPath.row`).